# Relation between compactness and invariant measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Recently I was informed that if we want to find an invariant measure on a infinite or finite space $X$, with no restriction on what kind of invariant measure we are looking for, then it's necessary for $X$ to be compact.

Can someone explain me this argument or give an example because I don't truly understand this argument.

Answer (score 1):

That is just not true. What about the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$? It is translation-invariant, but $\mathbb R$ is *not* compact.

What's important about $\mathbb R$ is that it is *locally* compact. Perhaps that you are interessted in [Haar's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#Haar.27s_theorem).

Comment: I believe the author was talking about a probability measure, but I agree that the question is not clearly written.

Comment: But now , if  we do it more specific , and we have a separable complete infinite banach space X, then for a gauss measure to be invariant we still need X to compactness or at least localy compactness ??